# SSH PHP - two parameters, one line

Tags: php, wordpress, shell, wp-cli

I want to run the following command in SSH:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /home/path/www/host.com/wp-cli.phar --path=/home/path/www/dev.host.com core version
```

But I get an info message from PHP. I think, that PHP recognize the "`--path`" but this is a parameter for the `.phar` file.

Is it possible to do that in one line?

Comment: You note that you get an info message. What is that message?

Comment: Something like:

Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
   php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
   ...

Comment: It seems like PHP says "I don't like the --path parameter"?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by setting `--path`? I am unaware of that args existence. Use `php --help` to see a list of arguments.

Comment: The --path parameter ist NOT for PHP - it is for the .phar File! This is the problem, PHP tries to interpret the --path parameter.